# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) duplicate symbol _sprites for _game

Tags: objective-c

I have a problem with my project. when i build my project, i have an error.
It shows duplicate symbol _sprites for _game

ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[image: Image for help]

Comment: Where in your code do you define sprites_for_game?  (I'll guess you have a .h file that defines the variable instead of just declaring it and that you're including that .h in multiple places.)

Comment: Have you searched on-line or SO already? For instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584781/apple-o-mach-linker-error and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435213/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation?rq=1

Comment: i define this variable in header helloworldlayer and use sprtes_for_game in helloworldlayer.mm

Comment: i did it by example  http://www.spritehelper.org/app/SpriteHelper_API_Documentation/DocumentationCocos2d/

Comment: Do you also include that header in AppDelegate and IntroLayer?  Perhaps you could edit your question to include the code.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error, it was because I defined a constant with the same name in two separate .m files. Once I changed the name in one of them, it compiled.

For example in my ViewController.m I had:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
const int IPHONE4 = 480;
```

and in my Menu.m:

```
#import "Menu.h"
const int IPHONE4 = 480;
```

I changed my Menu.m to:

```
#import "Menu.h"
const int IPHONE4H = 480;
```